# Clipping path in SVG not working in Safari

Tags: html, svg, safari, clipping

I've created a simple polygon in Illustrator and then created a clipping path (mask) in front of an image. I've exported it as an SVG file, and it renders perfectly in Chrome and Safari.

However, when I create an HTML file using the SVG data, it renders perfectly in Chrome but *not* Safari 6.0.2.

Not quite sure what I might be doing wrong; I've created examples of the SVG example ([personal site](http://roberskine.com/playground/clipping.svg)) and the HTML ([example on jsfiddle](http://cl.ly/MEzJ)).

Comment: hey @ErikDahlström, sorry I should have clarified. It's happening in the latest version of safari 6.0.2.

Comment: In general it's best not to package up your files as a zip, since it takes a little while to unpack them, and so less people will give it a try. For questions like this, put your example on a live site, or a JSFiddle.

Comment: Thanks @halfer, I appreciate the tip. I've made an edit to include links to examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must be running into a bug in Safari, instead of using `use` to apply the mask, just use the actual `polygon` element:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="700px" height="700px" viewBox="0 0 700 700" style="enable-background:new 0 0 700 700;" xml:space="preserve">
  <g>  

    <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
      <polygon id="SVGID_1_" points="576.35,444.245 670.595,350 576.349,255.754 576.349,123.651 444.246,123.651 350,29.405 255.755,123.651 122.96,123.651 122.96,256.446 29.405,350.001 122.96,443.555 122.96,577.041 256.446,577.041 350,670.595 443.554,577.041 576.35,577.041"/>
    </clipPath>

    <g id="LwhyVN.tif" style="clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_);">
      <image style="overflow:visible;" width="1024" height="768" id="Layer_0_1_" xlink:href="http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/071/9/e/Japanese_shiba_inu__shiba_dog__by_MogamiJ.jpg"  transform="matrix(0.8418 0 0 0.8418 27.5078 37.498)"></image>
    </g>

  </g>
</svg>
```

This works for me in Safari 6.

Comment: Dang, that's wayyyy simpler than my answer. I love it. Going to test in other browsers just to confirm and then I'll accept. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah, but your answer is interesting because it pinpoints at the origin of the problem: Safari doesn't find the reference unless it's served as xhtml. I suppose that even by simply serving html as xhtml through an .htaccess directive would also work.

Comment: Hm for sure, I guess that's true as well. Although, your solution is less markup doesn't require any server scripting. I don't have many masks to go through, I'll go this route for now and may need to come back to the xhtml fix later. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Also watch out if you have a base tag in your html as safari apparently adds the base to the id selector.

Comment: This is a good question that expands on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259032/using-base-tag-on-a-page-that-contains-svg-marker-elements-fails-to-render-marke

Comment: This can be answered as comment.

Answer (score 1):

Safari isn't a huge fan of clipPaths in SVG. Instead, it works perfectly when embedded within an old-school `<Object>` element. In order to do that though, I needed to make use of PHP headers to define the correct `Content-type` which is `application/xhtml+xml`. Without it,all that is served is `text/html`, where Safari (and older versions of modern browsers) will not display SVG.

In order to use PHP with SVG, I needed to add two additions to my webservers config file. In Apache, I added the type `psvg` to my mime-type file so that the releveant line reads like:
`image/svg+xml svg svgz psvg`

Next, I had to add an additional SVG-handler in the Apache config file, so that the relevant line reads like: `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php4 .phtml .psvg` so that any `.psvg` file is rendered as PHP.

So I created a new file called faces.psvg, and it looks like this:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: image/svg+xml");
    print('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>');
?>
<svg version="1.1"> //your svg file data </svg>
```

I then created a new .php file called index.php, and it looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
     <object type="image/svg+xml" data="faces.psvg" width="1120" height="800"></object>
</body>
</html>
```

and voilá, working svg clipping masks everywhere, even Mobile Safari.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the `clipPath` element inside a `defs` element:

```
<defs><clipPath></clipPath></defs>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this, used a `:before` and applied the clip and colour to that:

```
.field_captioned_carousel .teaser>.teasertextbg:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(70px 0%,100% 0,100% 100%,0 100%,0 70px);
    clip-path: polygon(50px 0%,100% 0,100% 100%,0 100%,0 50px);
    background-color:#ff0000;
}
```