# Printing SVG graphics that use clipping masks

Tags: svg, d3.js

I've created a detailed infographic that makes good use of clipping masks similar to the example seen here http://bl.ocks.org/enjalot/1503463. However, when I try to print my infographic, all the masked blocks become solid colored blocks and the mask seems to be ignored. Is there any way to fix this?

The only relavent post I found was [Clipping path in SVG not working in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372435/clipping-path-in-svg-not-working-in-safari) where they've forgone the using the <use> element.

Comment: have you by any chance used CSS?

Comment: can you show some code ..

Comment: My code is pretty much the same as the linked block above  http://bl.ocks.org/enjalot/1503463. I'm using enjalot’s method exactly. You can do a print preview on that page and you'll see the same issue.

Comment: This appears to be a Chrome browser issue. I'm not having problems in Safari.