# SVG Clip-path with "foreignObject" on iOS fails

Tags: ios, svg

I am trying to place YouTube(iframe) within a custom shape made with SVG.

```
    <svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <clippath id="rect">
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" rx="50" ry="50" />
    </clippath>

    <g clip-path="url(#rect)">   
    <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
    <iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="500px" height="500px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/m1mncceY4-4?enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
    </foreignObject></g></svg>
```

[Another sample page that attempts same goal](https://dev.to/alvarosaburido/the-magic-of-svg-clip-path-1lf0)
(Please check it out with any browser except the one on iOS)

The issue is that the clipping does not work on any browser on iOS. If you open the above sample, you would notice the clipping is gone.

Any advice appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: If you don't provide a `width` or `height` attribute to your `<rect>`, they will each default to 0.  So you will be clipping out everything.

Comment: Thanks, it was my typo. It works fine on almost all browsers. Why not on iOS??

Answer (score 0):

Does wrapping the `<clippath>` inside `<defs>` help?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14389784/708381

```
<defs><clipPath></clipPath></defs>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround: apply clip path to a HTML element within `<foreignObject>`

We need to tweak the clip path to be responsive for HTML elements like so:

```
  <clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" rx="0.1" ry="0.1" />
   </clipPath>
```

We need to add `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` and scale the element to a size of 1x1 units.
See also ["Eric Meyer: Scaling SVG Clipping Paths for CSS Use"](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2017/02/24/scaling-svg-clipping-paths-for-css-use)

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" rx="0.1" ry="0.1" />
    </clipPath>
    <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
      <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="clip-path:url(#clip)">
        <iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="500px" height="500px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/m1mncceY4-4"></iframe>
      </div>
    </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

The iframe is blocked in SO snippets - see [this codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/QWJjQNo)

`<foreignObject>` elements can introduce [**quite a lot of cross-browser rendering issues**.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=foreignObject)

So you should **consider a HTML/CSS approach** if your svg mostly contains HTML encapsuled in a `<foreignObject>`.

```html
<h3>HTML clipped</h3>
<div class="wrap" style="width:500px; aspect-ratio:1/1; clip-path:url(#clip)" >
  <iframe id="player" type="text/html" style="width:100%; height:100%;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/m1mncceY4-4?enablejsapi=1" ></iframe>
</div>

<h3>HTML rounded corners - no clip path</h3>
  <iframe id="player" type="text/html" style="width:500px; height:500px; border-radius: 50px;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/m1mncceY4-4?enablejsapi=1" ></iframe>

<!-- hidden svg clip asset -->
<svg style="width:0;height:0; position:absolute;">
  <clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" rx="0.1" ry="0.1" />
    </clipPath>
</svg>
```