# Problem rendering SVG in Chrome mobile and iOS Safari mobile

Tags: ios, google-chrome, svg, mobile, render

[Video of the problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEBh4azWmrE&feature=youtu.be)

The problem happens when there is a screen switch or browser minimization, and it only happens with the svg element. Has anyone encountered this? How to fix?
[imagem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0crtr.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to correct
good through this post

[Clipping path in SVG not working in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372435/clipping-path-in-svg-not-working-in-safari)
and this post  http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/clip-path.html
but I had to make some adaptations...

how did i fix this problem

1st first
had to change inline structure that comes before all sinline svgs

before:[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8Pbl.jpg
after:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Igqr.jpg)

so far I had already converted all patches into points

tools that helped me in this work:

1st crucial tool because it is possible to convert paths code into points codes for polygon
https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/full/zYORoNE  `software built on the code pen`

2st another tool to remove parts of unnecessary text such as curly braces ({}) spaces and commas that because the conversion tool transforms results into arrray

http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/replace-text/

3st another tool to remove lines breaks
https://www.textfixer.com/tools/remove-line-breaks.php

4st another last tool but not less important because it is possible to test directly online before inserting it in the code definitively
https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_polygon

that was a good tool

final result :

before
[before applying any new structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5Frm.jpg)

after: [after applying any new structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD1YJ.jpg)

I want to thank all the devs who collaborated with me, either by creating the free software and the post made, my thanks to everyone, the people of the stackoverflow, thanks!